# Insert multiple data in dynamically added table to database with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have a table with dynamically added rows. Something like this

[image]

User can add rows in each category (Basic, Type Rating, and General) dynamically. And when they click on "Save Record" button, the data will be stored in database.

I will share the code for one category (BASIC) only to represent the other categories.

This is how the table ('t_basic') in database looks like

[image]

**VIEW (body.php)** (only the first category (Basic))

```
<table id="myTable0" name="myTable0" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <h3>Subjects</h3>
    <tr style="font-size:18px; height:30px; color:#4d4d4d">
        <th class="col-md-2" colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">Category</th>
        <th class="col-md-3" style="text-align:center;">Work Scope</th>
        <th><div style="text-align:center">I</div></th>
        <th><div style="text-align:center">E</div></th>
        <th><div style="text-align:center">PI</div></th>
        <th><div style="text-align:center">PA</div></th>
        <th class="col-md-3" style="text-align:center;">ATA Chapters</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:25px; font-size:15px">
        <td class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center; color:#4d4d4d;"><b>Basic</b></td>
        <td class="col-md-1">
            <select style="height:30px" name="basic_category[]" class="form-control">
                <option>-</option>  
                <option>AP</option>
                <option>EA</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-3">
            <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="basic_workscope[]" placeholder="Type the workscope here">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="text-align: center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="basic_i[]">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="text-align: center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="basic_e[]">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="text-align: center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="basic_pi[]">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="text-align: center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="basic_pa[]">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-3">
            <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="basic_ata_chapter[]" placeholder="Type the ATA chapters here">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 20px;">                                                       
            <button onclick="deleteTable0()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="row">
    <button onclick="addTable0()" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="float: right; margin-right: 70px;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add
            </button>
</div> 


<script>    
function addTable0()
{

    var table0 = document.getElementById("myTable0");
    var row0 = table0.insertRow(2);
    var cell1_0 = row0.insertCell(0);
    var cell2_0 = row0.insertCell(1);
    var cell3_0 = row0.insertCell(2);
    var cell4_0 = row0.insertCell(3);
    var cell5_0 = row0.insertCell(4);
    var cell6_0 = row0.insertCell(5);
    var cell7_0 = row0.insertCell(6);
    var cell8_0 = row0.insertCell(7);
    var cell9_0 = row0.insertCell(8);
    row0.id = "newRow_0";
    cell1_0.innerHTML = "";
    cell2_0.id = "cell2_0";
    cell3_0.id = "cell3_0";
    cell4_0.id = "cell4_0";
    cell5_0.id = "cell5_0";
    cell6_0.id = "cell6_0";
    cell7_0.id = "cell7_0";
    cell8_0.id = "cell8_0";
    cell9_0.id = "cell9_0";
    $("#cell2_0").append('<select style="height:30px" name="basic_category[]" class="form-control"><option>-</option><option>AP</option><option>EA</option></select>');
    $("#cell3_0").append('<input type="text" class="form-control" name="basic_workscope[]" placeholder="Type the workscope here">');
    $("#cell4_0").append('<div style="text-align: center"><input type="checkbox" name="basic_i[]"></div>');
    $("#cell5_0").append('<div style="text-align: center"><input type="checkbox" name="basic_e[]"></div>');
    $("#cell6_0").append('<div style="text-align: center"><input type="checkbox" name="basic_pi[]"></div>');
    $("#cell7_0").append('<div style="text-align: center"><input type="checkbox" name="basic_pa[]"></div>');    
    $("#cell8_0").append('<input type="text" class="form-control" name="basic_ata_chapter[]" placeholder="Type the ATA chapters here">');
    $("#cell9_0").append('<button onclick="deleteTable0(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove" id="btn_delete" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>');
}

function deleteTable0(r)
{
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("0").deleteRow(i);
}
</script>
```

**CONTROLLER (instructor_con.php)**

```
$basic_data = array();

    $basic_category = $_POST["basic_category"];
    $basic_workscope = $_POST["basic_workscope"];
    $basic_i = $_POST["basic_i"];
    $basic_e = $_POST["basic_e"];
    $basic_pi = $_POST["basic_pi"];
    $basic_pa = $_POST["basic_pa"];
    $basic_ata_chapter = $_POST["basic_ata_chapter"];

    $basic_data[] = array($id_number, $basic_category, $basic_workscope, $basic_i, $basic_e, $basic_pi, $basic_pa, $basic_ata_chapter);

    $this->mod->insert_t_basic($basic_data);
```

**MODEL (mod.php)**

```
public function insert_t_basic($basic_data) {
    if(!empty($basic_data)) {

        foreach($basic_data as $value) {
            $this->db->insert('t_basic', $basic_data);
        }

    }
}
```

When I run the code above, I got this error message

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 1477

I have been spending 2 days trying to figure out what is the right method to insert each row data to the database. This problem seem compliated to me because I'm still new in codeigniter.

If you know any soultion to my problem, please let me know. Thank you in advance :")

Answer (score 1):

`$this->db->insert('t_basic', $basic_data);` with **`$basic_data`** must be an associative array (array with string as element's index key)

modify your `$basic_data` array in controller:

```
   $basic_data = [
      'basic_category' => $this->input->post('basic_category'),
      'basic_workscope' => $this->input->post('basic_workscope'),
      'basic_i' => $this->input->post('basic_i'),
      'basic_e' => $this->input->post('basic_e'),
      'basic_pi' => $this->input->post('basic_pi'),
      'basic_pa' => $this->input->post('basic_pa'),
      'basic_ata_chapter' => $this->input->post('basic_ata_chapter')
     ];
```

in CodeIgniter, You can use `$this->input->post()` instead of `$_POST[]` to retrieve POST data

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try to implement your suggestion. One thing, what is the difference between `$this->input->post()` and `$_POST[]` ?

Comment: Please refer to this CodeIgniter user guide:

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: @BanunAryani the logic for `input->post()` is the same except `input->post()` wont show a notice if it isn't defined (`isset`) and will just return null. `input->post` also allows for xss_filtering.